# Does array which appends CoreData Fetched Results element have to be of same type?

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to append a CoreData fetched results element to an array.

The array is a custom type of 'CommonWord', but when I check the type that's being appended to it, it shows as:

FetchedResults.Element

I'm not getting any values added to the array, is it because they're of different types?

If so, how do I go about adding a FetchedResults.Element type to the 'basics' array?

```
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: Thing.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var things: FetchedResults<Thing>
    @FetchRequest(entity: CommonWord.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \CommonWord.count, ascending: false)]) var commonWords: FetchedResults<CommonWord>
    
    @State private var changeVoiceSpeed: Float = 0.5
    
    let language: Language
    
    var commonWordsUsed: [CommonWord]? {
        var basics: [CommonWord]?
        
        print("common words are: \(commonWords)")
        let languageCommonWords = commonWords.filter { $0.subCategory?.language == language }
        for languageCommonWord in languageCommonWords {
            print("things filter: \(things.filter({ $0.foreign?.lowercased() == languageCommonWord.foreign?.lowercased() && $0.subCategory?.language == language }).count > 0)")
            if things.filter({ $0.foreign?.lowercased() == languageCommonWord.foreign?.lowercased() && $0.subCategory?.language == language }).count > 0 {
                basics?.append(languageCommonWord)
            }
        }
        print("basics are: \(basics ?? [])")
        return basics ?? []
    }
```

Comment: So you are trying to make a separate array of managed objects by filtering the `FetchRequest`. As you have run into, you can't do that. What is your use case? You haven't shown your view code, but most likely your easiest solution is to filter the `FetchRequest` when you need the filtered list. If you ONLY need the filtered list in your view, you can use a predicate to filter what you get.

Comment: Likely isn’t appending because basics is never initialized. Instead of using optional start it with an empty array